# Oracle database connectivity issue

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle database instance on my local machine , which i try to connect to .

Using SQL Developer , i can connect to it . But when i use sqlplus i cannot connect to the instance.

The error message i get is

```
ORA-28547:connection to server failed,probable oracle net admin error.
```

I tried restarting my TNS service but still the issue persists.

And i need to connect to sqlplus because  i need to import the dumps using

```
impdp system/***** schemas=abcd dumpfile=DUMP_500.dmp
```

Please let me know what other information is needed , so that i can post

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same tnsnames.ora file for your SQL*Plus that your SQL Developer is using? Also try adding `SQL_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)` to your sqlnet.ora file.

Comment: Its worksss!!!! Thank you very much. I was thinking of deleting my instance and getting a new one..

Comment: i am not sure if we can accept a comment as the correct answer. Let me know if you want to answer here.Or else i can , so that it will help someone else.Thanks

Comment: I'll add it an an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the same tnsnames.ora file for your SQL*Plus that your SQL Developer is using?

Also try adding `SQL_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)` to your sqlnet.ora file.

Comment: I added this an an aswer as @Barry said that it had solved the issue. Hopefully it'll help any future people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

i added `SQL_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)` to my sqlnet.ora file and it worked